# How to use a condition as a Google Analytics View Filter

Tags: google-analytics, filtering

I want to track all users activity on condition that they have visited any page that ends in `ending.php`.

Using advanced segments this is easy using a condition. With View Filters I cant seem to find a condition option.

I want to create a View in Analytic's that tracks all pages of users who also viewed a certain page.

Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an "Include" filter for a view, where the rule is:

```
Filter Field: Request URI
Filter Pattern: .*\/ending\.php$
```

What this filter does is include, for the specific view, ANY traffic that ends with "ending.php".